# How to redirect IP address to another IP address using netsh windows tool?

Tags: windows, netsh

My question is : how to redirect IP address to another IP address

ex: 
10.10.10.10 -> 20.20.20.20 (these IP are external)

This answer shows me how to map IP adress to localhost.
[Can I redirect/route IP adress to another IP address (windows)](https://serverfault.com/questions/712970/can-i-map-ip-adress-to-another-ip-address-windows)

Regards

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do in some more detail? What do you mean by 'map'? Are you trying to forward traffic to that address, or are you trying to add another address to the same interface so it has multiple addresses?

Comment: I try to redirect. Both address are external. 

Ex:  redirect 146.112.61.106 to  37.59.14.123

Comment: NAT was invented to answer what I think you are asking for (the term redirect makes little sense in the IP terminology, unless you are specifically asking about gateway redirection).